# How to customize plugins in janus, a vim distribution?

Tags: vim, customization, janus

[Janus](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus) is good piece of pre-configured ViM [and its plugins]. There are two different hooks *.vimrc.before* which runs before Janus is loaded, and *.vimrc.after* which runs after Janus is loaded but before any plugins are loaded.

All seems fine, but I couldn't find a way/place to add plugin-specific configuration. For instance, I'd like to use [rails.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails)'s Rnavcommand to add various navigation commands like "Rpresenter", "Ruploader", etc.,

`Rnavcommand presenter app/presenters`

I couldn't do this in *.vimrc.after* because **rails.vim** is not loaded by the time this file gets executed.

Answer (score 3):

Janus's plugin-specific settings are in [`janus/vim/tools/janus/after/plugin/`](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus/tree/master/janus/vim/tools/janus/after/plugin). I have no idea where they are once the whole thing is installed.

But I feel the need to say *Drop Janus.* Using your own `~/.vimrc` and installing your plugins yourself is not that hard or time consuming and one of the benefits is that you actually know where, how and why things are how they are.

Comment: thanks! This seems sensible. After spending about half a day trying to find a place to customize plugins, it appears Janus is all not worth it.

Comment: +1 For dropping this type of configuration once you understand enough to maintain your own settings.

Answer (score 0):

When a plugin hasn't yet been loaded, but you need its functionality (e.g. to define custom commands based on it), you can always explicitly source the plugin script, and then do the definition after that:

```
:runtime plugin/rails.vim
:Rnavcommand presenter app/presenters
```

The canonical include-guard which is / should be included in all plugins avoids that the plugin is re-defined when it is later sourced again as part of the regular initialization sequence.

---

Alternatively, the *after* directories are meant for stuff that need to run after a dependent script. I don't know / don't recommend using distributions like *Janus*, but assuming the Rails plugin is located at `~/.janus/rails/plugin/rails.vim`, the corresponding *after* location would be `~/.janus/rails/after/plugin/rails.vim`.